# WCF GET service xml return

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

Here is what I get after I keyed in my GET url at web browser. Where shall I go to to change the xmlns to something else? THanks.

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">-2202.68</string>
```

Here is the starting of my code:

```
namespace MSData
{

    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class Service
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        public string AdjustBalance(string Uid, string Adjustment)
    {
    ... ... ... ...
```

Comment: What do you want to change it to?  Why do you think it needs to be changed?

Comment: I don't know. something that I am curious how to change.... is that automatically assigned?